# Issues with the output format of hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

So I was trying to create a program that resembles a grocery list where the user puts the item and its associated cost and it would display it as a form of a list. So I created this:

```
arr = []
arr2 = []
entry = " "

while entry != "q"
  print "Enter your item: "
  item = gets.chomp
  print "Enter the associated cost: "
  cost = gets.chomp.to_f
  print "Press any key to continue or 'q' to quit: "
  entry = gets.chomp

  arr << item
  arr2 << cost
end

h = { arr => arr2 }   

for k,v in h
  puts "#{k} costs #{v}"
end
```

(Code is probably very inefficient, but with my limited starter knowledge it's the best I can do)

So my problem is when I try more than two items the results would display like this (Let's say I used Banana and Kiwi for item and put a random number for their costs):

```
["Banana", "Kiwi"] costs [2.0, 3,0]
```

I, however, would like it to display like this:

```
Banana costs $2.00

Kiwi costs $3.00
```

I know it probably has to do something with this line:

```
h = { arr => arr2 }
```

But I just don't know what I can change about it. I already spend hours trying to figure out how it works so if anyone can give me a hint or help me out I would appreciate it! (Also my apologies for the vague title, didn't know better on how to describe it...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you are correct. Problem is with this line `h = { arr => arr2 }`. This line will create a hash like `h = {["Banana", "Kiwi"] => [2.0, 3,0]}`.

1) You can modify your code as below if you want to use two arrays.

```
(0...arr.length).each do |ind|
  puts "#{arr[ind]} costs $#{arr2[ind]}"
end
```

2) Better, you can use a hash to store the item and it's cost and then iterate over it to show the results

```
hash = {}
entry = " "

while entry != "q"
  print "Enter your item: "
  item = gets.chomp

  print "Enter the associated cost: "
  cost = gets.chomp.to_f

  print "Press any key to continue or 'q' to quit: "
  entry = gets.chomp

  hash[item] = cost
end

hash.each do |k,v|
  puts "#{k} costs $#{v}"
end
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you that is really helpful, didn't know it was that simple.

Answer (score 2):

You are storing the item names and their costs in 2 different arrays. So, if want to keep your storage structure like that only, you will need to modify the display of result as below:

```
arr.each_with_index do |item, i|
  puts "#{item} costs #{arr2[i]}"
end
```

But a better approach would be to store all the data in 1 hash instead of 2 arrays.

```
items = {}
entry = " "

while entry != "q"
  print "Enter your item: "
  item = gets.chomp
  print "Enter the associated cost: "
  cost = gets.chomp.to_f

  print "Press any key to continue or 'q' to quit: "
  entry = gets.chomp

  items[item] = cost
end

items.each do |item, cost|
  puts "#{item} costs #{cost}"
end
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Definitely helpful! Thank you for taking your time to respond!